# What's the smallest footprint dual H-bridge?

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, footprint

I am designing a circuit with 4 small electric motors. The motors I selected are SMT and are driven by 3V power source. It makes sense to drive each pair of motors by a dual H-bridge, but I can't find a part small enough. Another option is to use a number of small simple parts instead of the integrated part, I have calculated that I would need at least 16 resistors, 12 transistors and 8 diodes, but even when using 0402, VMT3 and SOD-923 packages this takes a considerable area of the board. Ideally I need a BGA or QFN part to save space on the board.

Comment: Do you have a non-shopping (off-topic) question?

Comment: Is this for a quadcopter?

Comment: Smaller packages = lower power handling capability usually.  Keep that in mind as you "shop".

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8841.pdf?ts=1592407287687&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Nope, not a quadcopter, more like a toy car with independent wheel control.

Comment: @KyleB SOP28 is way too huge and I don't need that much power for such small motors. The motors I'm using are rated for 3V@60mA with no load and the the power source is a coin cell battery.

Comment: 3V@60mA no load... What is it gonna be when they're loaded?   The current's gonna go up significantly.     Also - You might wanna have a look at what a coin-cell battery can output.    They are not meant to output that level of current - They are really meant for applications in milli-to-micro ampere levels.    Don't take the 'mA-Hr' rating and assume you can draw that many milliamps - That's not what that rating means.      
    READ THIS: 
  https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/lithiumcoin_appman.pdf      ESPECIALLY the part about 'internal resistance'.    Ask questions if you don't understand

Comment: Here's a single H-bridge IC, in a package about the size of a grain of rice.      https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsba4e/slvsba4e.pdf?ts=1592497824998&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F